# use IDs instead of instances to create new objects with foreign keys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I want to create a new Django ORM object with three foreign keys. I got the IDs of the foreign rows already, and I mean - that's all I need to fill the foreign key columns in my new row, right? However, I don't seem able to create the new row without hitting the DB three times to instantiate objects out of those IDs.

So what I need to do:

```
foreign_object = models.ForeignObject.get(pk=foreign_object_id)
a = models.Object1.get_or_create(f = foreign_object)
```

What I'd like to do:

```
a = models.Object1.get_or_create(f_id = foreign_object_id)
```

`f_id` however is not a field Django recognizes. If I just assign `foreign_object_id` to `f` (I think I recall this works in some cases), Django complains that it wants a `ForeignObject` instance instead of an int.

Any way to do this?

Comment: this should work. what error are you getting? could you show some model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the double-underscore notation in this case

eg

```
a = models.Object1.get_or_create(f__pk=foreign_object_id)
```